# Android : Retrieve multiples Elements from Html using JSoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want to retrieve a `title` from a `div`, a `start hour` and an `end hour` all of that from a big `div` called `day` and inside another `div` called `event`

I need to had these `items` to a `list` but right now i'am stuck here because it can't retrieve my `3 elements`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://terry.gonguet.com/cal/?g=tp11").get();
Elements days = doc.select("div[class=day]");
Elements event = doc.select("div[class=event]");
for(Element day : days)
{
    System.out.println(" : " + day.text());
    for(Element ev : event)
    {

        Element title = ev.select("div[class=title]").first();
        Element starthour = ev.select("div[class=bub right top]").first();
        Element endhour = ev.select("div[class=bub right bottom]").first();
        System.out.println(title.text()+starthour.text()+endhour.text());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of there is no div in that document which have only `day` as class argument. They all have `day` class combined with another class which prevents `div[class=day]` from finding such div. Same problem applies to `div[class=event]` selector.

To solve it use CSS query syntax in which `.` operator is used to describe class attribute
(hint: if you want to select element which has few classes you can use `element.class1.class2`).

So instead of

```
select("div[class=day]");
select("div[class=event]");
```

use

```
select("div.day");
select("div.event");
```

Also instead of

```
ev.select("div[class=bub right top]");
ev.select("div[class=bub right bottom]");
```

you could try using

```
ev.select("div.bub.right.top");
ev.select("div.bub.right.bottom]");
```

This will allow you to find div which has all these classes (even if they are not in same order or there are more classes then mentioned in selector).

Comment: I can't say which elements you want to get exactly so I can't help you farther. Feel free to leave a comment about this answer (did it help, do you have any farther problems).

Comment: Ok so it seems to work better.The only think that doest work is that i'am trying to get a div who as 3 classes :bub right bottom so i can i get to an element too ? Same thing for :bub right top

Comment: @yoyani If you have a div with three classes :bub right bottom, use the following CSS query to select it: `div.bub.right.bottom`.

Comment: @yoyani Like I said in answer, if you have element with many classes you can use form `element.class1.class2`, so div with classes `bub right bottom` can be selected using CSS query `div.bub.right.bottom`. But if you wan to find div with only these classes (and no other classes mentioned in `class=` attribute then `select("div[class=bub right bottom]")` should work fine.

Comment: To be more precise if we have divs like `<div class='bar foo'>` `<div class='foo bar'>` `<div class='foo bar baz'>` then `div.foo.bar` will find them all (despite order of values in class attributes and fact that there may be more classes than selected). But `div[class=foo bar]` will find only `<div class='foo bar'>` (rest will be ignored because `[attribute=text]` selector is comparing text as string and `'bar foo'!='foo bar'`, same about `foo bar baz`).